# Identifying transactional trends

Tags: trend, anomaly-detection

I'm not sure if this is the right forum but here goes:

I have a requirement to attempt spot patterns in data , more specifically bank transaction data. There is transaction date, amount, description e.g.

```
6/2/2017 COFFEE 5$
6/2/2017 EMPLOYER DEPOSIT 1000$
10/2/2017 GROCERIES 50$
20/2/2017 EMPLOYER DEPOSIT 1005$
20/2/2017 GROCERIES 120$
```

There are hundreds of other entries for general transactions and credit card entries.

So in the above example would want to determine the employee deposit trend every two weeks.

I have extensive C#/general programming experience, just need some guidance as to what to look into. I understand this probably isn't a simple solution but any suggestions what areas to focus on would be appreciated.

If this isnt' the correct forum please let me know which one to go to.

Comment: Search this site for anomaly detection, there are many posts!

Answer (score 0):

One of the options is to use ARIMA model that has implemented in many languages.

A very nice introduction is here (4 parts of reading, but worth to spend the time): http://ucanalytics.com/blogs/forecasting-time-series-analysis-manufacturing-case-study-example-part-1/